# launch4j и Ubuntu. Проблема с кириллицей

Tags: java, ubuntu, кириллица

Здравствуйте. Использую Ubuntu 14.04. Сейчас мне необходимо сделать из .jar-файла .exe-файл. При использовании launch4j возникает проблема с отображением кириллицы. При запуске .jar-файла все работает как надо. Что можно использовать вместо launch4j для этих целей?

Comment: Вы этот exe файл собрались запускать в Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пытаетесь запустить свой exe файл в Ubuntu, то, скорее всего, он запускается в Wine со всем сопутствующем  Wine окружением - шрифтами и пр. При запуске jar файла, он стартует непосредственно в Ubuntu. Не надо делать никаких exe файлов - эти глупости используются в крайне исключительных случаях и на мой взгляд не дают никаких преимуществ перед использованием обычного jar, запускаемого через bat или sh сценарий.